# What is the reason for error in CMake?

Tags: cmake

I am running the following script to change the name by which I call my GROMACS command from `gmx` to `gmx_196g`. The script employs CMake:

```
cd gromacs-2019.6/build_stage3/
suffix=196g

install_path=/home/my_username/software/gmx_2019/.local

OPTFLAGS="-Ofast -mtune=broadwell"
cmake3 .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
        -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=icc -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE="$OPTFLAGS" \
        -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=icpc -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE="$OPTFLAGS" \
        -DGMX_MPI=ON -DGMX_OPENMP=ON \ -DGMX_GPU=CUDA -DGMX_CUDA_TARGET_SM=60 \
        -DGMX_SIMD=AVX2_256 -DGMX_DOUBLE=OFF \ -DGMX_FFT_LIBRARY=mkl \
        -DGMX_DEFAULT_SUFFIX=OFF -DGMX_BINARY_SUFFIX=_${suffix} -DGMX_LIBS_SUFFIX=_${suffix} \
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${install_path}

make -j 8 make install

cd ../../
```

However, I am receiving this error:

```
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/my_username/software/gmx_2019/gromacs-2019.6/build_stage3/ -DGMX_FFT_LIBRARY=mkl" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
make: *** No rule to make target 'make'.  Stop.
```

Why is the error highlighting -DGMX_FFT_LIBRARY=mkl and my source directory? I am confused as to why this is happening... Any advice you have would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslash characters in this context are meant to be *line continuation characters*, escaping the literal newlines.

When you place a backslash in the middle of a line, it is escaping the following character, so for example in

```
    -DGMX_MPI=ON -DGMX_OPENMP=ON \ -DGMX_GPU=CUDA -DGMX_CUDA_TARGET_SM=60 \
```

the `\ -DGMX_GPU=CUDA` is read as a single token starting with a literal space. Because it doesn't begin with a dash, `cmake` is interpreting it as a source directory instead of an option.

Either remove such superfluous backslashes

```
    -DGMX_MPI=ON -DGMX_OPENMP=ON -DGMX_GPU=CUDA -DGMX_CUDA_TARGET_SM=60 \
```

or use them as intended i.e. as line-continuations

```
    -DGMX_MPI=ON -DGMX_OPENMP=ON \ 
    -DGMX_GPU=CUDA -DGMX_CUDA_TARGET_SM=60 \
```

making sure that there are no trailing characters after the `\`

Comment: Thank you @steeldriver. that worked.